# Add scope and retrieve it after firebase authentication using Provider

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

In firebase backend I know how to authenticate user via many technics like email and password, Facebook authentication, google authentication , link and so on.
So in web v9 modular to create provider object we use :
`const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()` and to add email scope we proceed like this:
`provider.addScope('email')`
After user login we get result.user object like this:

```
signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
     .then((result)=>{
      storeUser(result.user);
     })
     .catch((err)=>{
     // console.log(`google err --->${err.message}`);
     })
     .finally(()=>{});
```

The big question is: How could we retrieve the email after the successful login?

Answer (score 0):

The `result` is an [`UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usercredential.md#usercredential_interface) object. To get the email, try:

```
const userEmail = result.user.email
```

Comment: hi @Dharmaraj , `result.user.email` returns null because email is not a direct property of user and i retrieved registration and login date using `result.user.metadata` instead this object contains only these two properies . thanks any way for you advice.

Answer (score 0):

after many researches I finally found resolution for my issue

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser;

if (user !== null) {
  user.providerData.forEach((profile) => {
    console.log("Sign-in provider: " + profile.providerId);
    console.log("  Provider-specific UID: " + profile.uid);
    console.log("  Name: " + profile.displayName);
    console.log("  Email: " + profile.email);
    console.log("  Photo URL: " + profile.photoURL);
  });
}
```

[Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)